# Cannot automatically close second window with QInputDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Issue in my code sample:
On "Select..." the selection dialog appears and works basically, but closing it with "Ok" or "Cancel", unfortunately leaves a second window open (title "New Popup"), which is very ugly... :/ I am searching for the way to close that automatically after the user applied the selection in the list, returning to the main window (and the data processing should still work of course).

Thanks for any help! :)

Background: Inside a basic pyqt5 window application, I created a simple list selection as a second (popup) window (separate class), where the user can select an item and the result is then processed in the main window class.
That works basically but I've got an issue with correctly closing the popup window and I was not able to find a solution since hours... Basically I tried `self.close`, `self.destroy`, `self.hide` etc. but nothing had an effect, probably I am missing a piece.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QInputDialog, QLabel, QVBoxLayout


class PopupDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PopupDialog, self).__init__()
        self.selected_item = None
        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("New Popup")
        self.setMinimumWidth(400)

        items = ("C", "C++", "Java", "Python")
        item, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "select input dialog",
                    "list of languages", items, 0, False)
        self.selected_item = item


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumWidth(600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select...")
        button.clicked.connect(self.get_input)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.le)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_input(self):
        popup = PopupDialog()
        popup.exec_()
        print("got selection data: ", popup.selected_item)
        self.le.setText(popup.selected_item)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Delete the line `popup.exec_()`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! :) ...such an easy solution, feel a little stupid... I just thought that popup.exec_() line would be neccessary for reading out the selected values as it was included in various examples giving the base for my own version.

Would you mind giving me a little hint in which kind of situation that line could have been needed? ...just to know the general purpose of it.

Comment: The first dialog box is `QInputDialog`. The second thing you do not need is `popup.exec _ ()`.